# Running GRASS functions in QGIS 2.4 from python console

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis

I am using qgis 2.4 and i am looking for the "easiest" way to execute e.g. the r.in.gdal function from the python console in qgis.

Specifically for r.in.gdal, I could not found this function in processing module (i.e. import processing; processing.alglist('r.in')), thus, processing module seems not to be the way to go ?!?

Before executing a grass command the mapset needs to be opened. Which command does this job?

Answer (score 1):

[r.in.gdal](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.in.gdal.html) is a command to import rasters into GRASS GIS, not into  QGIS

There are two options to use GRASS GIS in QGIS:

1) with the grass plugin

- you are working in GRASS GIS and you can use  `r.in.gdal` in the **Python console of GRASS GIS** to import a raster into a Location/Mapset.

2) from processing

- you are working in QGIS with a "virtual" Location/Mapset that has nothing to do with the Location/Mapset of 1), therefore `r.in.gdal` is useless -> use the the [PyQGIS solution](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html) in the **Python console of QGIS**

You can also use [osgeo.gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.11.1) to import a raster into a GRASS GIS Location/Mapset.